# How to show that ${1\over \Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\cdot{\mathrm dx\over e^{(n+1)x}-e^{nx}}=\zeta(s)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{1\over k^{s}}?$

Tags: integration

How do we prove $(1)$
$${1\over \Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\cdot{\mathrm dx\over e^{(n+1)x}-e^{nx}}=\zeta(s)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{1\over k^{s}}?\tag1$$

$s\ge2$ and $n\ge0$

Setting $n=0$ we have the well-known [zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)

$${1\over \Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\cdot{\mathrm dx\over e^{x}-1}=\zeta(s)\tag2$$

Comment: Have you tried factoring the $e^{nx}$ out of the denominator? My guess is integration by parts after that.

Comment: oh yeah, I didn't see that, thank you.

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-kx} dx =\int_0^\infty (y/k)^{s-1} e^{-ky} d(y/k)= k^{-s} \Gamma(s), \qquad \frac{e^{-(n+1)x}}{1-e^{-x}} = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty e^{-kx}$$ @Merkh

Comment: @reuns: I would propose you to turn these comments into an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the identity (sum of geometric series)
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} r^k = \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}
\leftrightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{kx} = \frac{1-e^{nx}}{1-e^x}$$
to write
\begin{eqnarray}
I &=& \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty dx \, x^{s-1} 
\frac{e^{-nx}}{e^x-1} \\
&=&\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty dx \, x^{s-1} e^{-nx} \left[
\frac{e^{nx}}{e^x-1} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{kx} \right] \\
&=&\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty dx \, x^{s-1}\left[
\frac{1}{e^x-1} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{(k-n)x} \right] \\
&=& \zeta(s) - \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty dx \, x^{s-1}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{(k-n)x} \\
&=& \zeta(s) - \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_0^\infty dx \, x^{s-1} e^{-(n-k)x} \\
&=& \zeta(s) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (n-k)^{-s}\\
&=& \zeta(s) - \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{-s}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: There is a mismatch between the exponent of $k$ in this answer and the question. I'm not sure if something changed.

Comment: I believe the original equality is incorrect, and $k^{-s}$ is the correct form.

Comment: The question has been edited now. Good work.